# Why are we [still] not on the footer?

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

This completely feels like asking for an underground parking spot at work, but... there's at least<sub><sup><sup>1</sup></sup></sub> one spot left in the page footer area, in the section we'd belong under:

[image: one spot left!]

Why isn't Code Review on there?

---

**Update:** As of sometime this year, Code Review now appears on the SE footer.

---

<sub><sup><sup>1</sup></sup> looking at the Life/Arts section it seems there are actually at least 4 spots left.</sub>

Comment: Just nitpicking, but it looks a lot like there's actually 8 "slots" in each column, it's just that the middle one takes up more vertical space due to GIS. In which case, there isn't a "free" slot (though I would make the case that there's **plenty** of sites there that CR should take precedence over in either case).

Comment: @Zak aw, you're right. Now it *really* feels like asking for an underground parking spot.

Comment: @Zak it's not really fair to say if a site should take precedence over another

Comment: @Quill except.... *size matters* ;-)

Comment: @Quill It's got nothing to do with fair. There are more sites than there are slots, so there should be some criteria that decides which sites go where. Now that CR is graduated, I struggle to think of a criteria that wouldn't put it somewhere in that list.

Comment: All of those sites on there have graduated (before us even), it's a simple matter of space

Comment: @Zak How about when [sites graduate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145944/260461)?
This also prevents site superiority comments such as "there's __plenty__ of sites there that CR should take precedence over".